# Who governed the area of Rahadoum between -2764 and 2555 AR?

Tags: lore, pathfinder-2e

I'm trying to piece together the history of Rahadoum. It's clear that the modern nation of Rahadoum didn't exist until around 2555 - 2560, but I can't quite figure out the prior political history of the area. My primary source is *Lost Omens: World Guide*; I'm unaware of the 1e resources that may be important.

What I think I understand:

- **The Jistka Empire** is founded in -4120 and is conquered by Osirion in -2764.
- ??
- **Rahadoum** is founded in 2555-2560, with the enactment of the Laws of Mortality and the end of the Oath Wars.

Unfortunately, the middle 5,000 years is somewhat murky. Although Osirian conquers the Jistka Empire, there is no mention of them ruling the area that is now Rahadoum. The timeline in the sidebar does mention Thuvian independence from Osirion, but no explicit mention is made of Rahadoum.

Who is governing Rahadoum between -2764 (when Osirion conquers it) and 2555 (when the modern state is founded)? Is it a part of Osirion? Are there other states before Radahoum?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Wiki has a convenient [Timeline of Rahadoum](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Rahadoum) about just this topic. The two lines that will be of most interest to you are

> **-2587 AR** Pharaoh An-Hepsu II founds the port city of Totra in Osirion. The fleets of the An dynasty will eventually sail from here in what is known as the Great Atoqua – the subjugation of large parts of Thuvia and Rahadoum.
>
> **-1431 AR** The rule of the Four Pharaohs of Ascension comes to an end, and Osirion enters into a decline; *eventually Rahadoum will free itself of Osirion influence and become a region of isolated city-states.*

From -2587 through sometime after -1431, it was primarily Osirion land. At that point it began to **break down to local leadership** until the Oath Wars begin in 2498 and end in 2555 with the Laws of Morality essentially defining/unifying Rahadoum.

The sourcing on the Wiki is the "Inner Sea World Guide", "Osirion, Land of Pharaohs", and Pathfinder Chronicles "Campaign Setting" if you'd like to read more.